# How to show variables in Python Console after running code in Pycharm?

Tags: python, variables, pycharm, console

I am having a problem in PyCharm (2022.3.1) that the variables of my code are not showing in the right-bottom area of "Variables" in Python Console in PyCharm.

This function is extremely useful when coding. You can keep track of the changes and data-type of your variables.

How to solve it?

Comment: variables in the python console only show interactively defined variables from that session .... running your code in pcharm debug mode with breakpoints should show you something similar with your code

Answer (score 2):

The problem mentioned was solved and I will described, here, how to do it:

I ran a simple code with two variables. The code runs fine but the variables do not show (in the red circle area, as they should be).
[Se this first first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9jBa.jpg)

If I add a new variables manually in the Python Console it will show in the variable area [as it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOxzq.jpg)

So how did I solve this issue?

You will need to change the **Debug configurations** as [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlIVQ.png), and check the box **"Run with Python Console"**, then *Apply*, *Ok*.

After that when you run your code, your variables will be shown in the variables tab at the bottom-right-corner, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jawWu.jpg).

After that you will also be able to type new variables in the Python Console and they will immediately be shown in the variable tab.

Comment: Thank you for this solution!
I wanted to ask for a clarification: the variables are only listed when the program finishes?

Comment: Yes, just after the full code runs. 

To be sure your code ran fully and did not stay stuck in a loop, for example, add in the last line of your code a:

print("Full code ran and done!")

and observe if it will be printed on the Python console.

Note that I did these screenshots in an older version of PyCharm. I am currently using the newest (2023.2.1 - Community Edition) and the GUI of Pycharm to solve this issue is a bit different but it remains the same principle.